# In dynamic linking, how does the .exe know where to search for the library when it is updated?

Tags: c++, c, dynamic, linker, libraries

It is my understanding that when a C program uses dynamic linking, the compiled version of the program (.exe) stores the memory address of the library somewhere. How about when the program is installed on someone else's computer, isn't the location of the library different? Or, when you update the library, wouldn't its memory address be different?

Comment: Which operating system ?

Comment: Is this WinX or POSIX (ELF)? The mechanisms are different

Comment: .exe hints to MS windows - there is a specific order of directories which are looked up - among these C:\Windows\System32, current working directory and the direcory the .exe file resides in and yet some others. Don't know any more which was the order, being off of windows for too long now... However, if the library (dll) is located in any of these directories, the program will find it.

Comment: ***stores the memory address of the library somewhere. How about when the program is installed on someone else's computer, isn't the location of the library different?*** Remember each process gets its own virtual address space. Although you seem to be talking about 2 different concepts here. The physical location of a dynamic library and the address the library loads in memory.

Comment: One other thing to consider is modern operating systems randomize the addresses used to load your process. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Answer (score 1):

Neither C nor C++ specifies how this works.  It's different for the different operating systems and exe formats.  To know the specifics you need to look into how your implementation does things.

The short answer to your question is that the OS sets the environment up within which your program runs.  It has to attach the program to the right places, or at the least notify it.  Generally you start your program and the format tells the OS what libraries it should load and then it links up the addresses in some way.

There's usually a way to do this manually as well and directly request a library to be loaded during runtime.  The automatic linking of calls though may not happen in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, location of the library is different on different computers. And yes, when you update the library, its memory address is different. That is why the address of dynamically linked function cannot be hardwired in the executable file. Instead, only its name and the name of hosting library (without path specification) is stored in PE format.

Before the program.exe starts, OS loader looks for required DLL, loads it to the virtual memory space of starting program, finds current addresses of required functions from this DLL and writes them to Imported Address Table (IAT).

When your program calls some dynamically linked function, it actually makes an indirect CALL of its address in IAT.